# Java: Replace space with %20. Why this prints Mr%20 A and not Mr%20A

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi I'm trying to replace the space in String to %20. 
Example 
input: Mr A
output: Mr%20A

I cannot understand why my code is printing "Mr%20 A". I want to print "Mr%20A", so please tell me how do I go about doing that? Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestAnswer {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println(isPermutation("aXbcx", "xbcaX"));
        System.out.println(URLify("Mr A"));
    }


    static String URLify(String s){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            char  c = s.charAt(i);
            if(c == ' '){
                sb.append("%20");

            }

            sb.append(c);

        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: What 'else' could it be

Comment: Why not simply do `s.replace(" ", "%20")`?

Comment: Why not just use [URLEncoder#encode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)?

Comment: @sudo because that would replace the space with `+` not `%20`

Comment: (Please remove blank lines not separating anything purposely.)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of looping over the `String` and recreating it using a `StringBuilder`, consider using this single line of code:

```
s = s.replace(" ", "%20");
```

Answer (score 4):

After you append `"%20"` (in case of `c == ' '`) you also append `c`:

```
char  c = s.charAt(i);
if(c == ' '){
    sb.append("%20");
}
sb.append(c); //here
```

The solution is to append `c` only when it is not `' '`.

**Solution:**

```
char  c = s.charAt(i);
if(c == ' '){
    sb.append("%20");
}else{
    sb.append(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By commenting out

```
//System.out.println(isPermutation("aXbcx", "xbcaX"));
```

I can see you are solving CTCI

@sudo answered your question, I just want to suggest a better solution

Your solution might be good enough but it is worth to explain that StringBuilder.append will double the char array size which will contain the string for each append if the capacity is not enough, until it can hold the string

My solution will iterate twice over the original string but will not expand the returned char array

```
private static char[] URLify(char[] original) {
    char charToReplace = ' ';
    char[] replacement = new char[]{'%', '2', '0'};
    // count charToReplace, in our case, count spaces
    int numCharsToReplace = 0;
    for (char c : original) if (c == charToReplace) numCharsToReplace++;
    // creating new fixed char array to return
    int resultSize = original.length + (numCharsToReplace * replacement.length) - numCharsToReplace;
    char[] result = new char[resultSize];
    // we need two indexes,one to iterate the result char array, second to iterate the original
    int i = 0, originalIdx = 0;
    // until we set all new array of chars cells
    while (i < resultSize) {
        // get original character
        char curOriginalChar = original[originalIdx];
        // this condition is first because I assume real URL will not contain as much spaces as chars
        // if current character is not one we need to replace, copy
        if (curOriginalChar != charToReplace) {
            result[i] = curOriginalChar;
            // for readable code the index incremented in new line
            // could be replaced with "result[i++] = curOriginalChar;"
            i++;
        }
        else {
            for (char c : replacement) {
                result[i] = c;
                i++;
            }
        }
        originalIdx++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Utility to get StringBuilder real char array length

```
/**
 * StringBuilder's member "char value[]" is the character array stored inside StringBuilder, and it's
 * reference can be accessed only through getValue method, which is not public
 * so a little hack so we can know what is the char array size created
 */
private static int getStringBuilderCharSize(StringBuilder sb) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field stringBuilderCharField = StringBuilder.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("value");
    stringBuilderCharField.setAccessible(true);
    char[] chars = (char[]) stringBuilderCharField.get(sb);
    return chars.length;
}
```

Usage example

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        String original = "Mr & Mrs Smith";
        char[] urlify = URLify(original.toCharArray());
        System.out.println(new String(urlify) + "|" + urlify.length);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : original.toCharArray())
            if (c != ' ') sb.append(c);
            else sb.append("%20");
        System.out.println(sb.toString() + "|" + getStringBuilderCharSize(sb));
    }
```

Output :

```
Mr%20&%20Mrs%20Smith|20
Mr%20&%20Mrs%20Smith|34
```

14 cells saved ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are checking if a character is a space and appending a "%20" to the StringBuilder. But, the sb.append(c) statement after the if condition causes the space to be appended as well.
You could add the continue keyword after appending "%20" inside the if case.

So your code should look something like this:

```
static String URLify(String s){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            char  c = s.charAt(i);
            if(c == ' '){
                sb.append("%20");
                continue;
            }

            sb.append(c);

        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```